# countdown (up) plugin from jquery - set start value from number

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

i' m looking for a jquery plugin where i can specify the startposition by a number. So if i want the timer to start from 2 minutes 34 seconds, then i specify it by 154, or i set the minutes to 2 and seconds to 34. So any solution where i can start it with a server side value.

For instance the countid ( http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-jQuery-Counter-Timer-Plugin-countid.html ) would be perfect and enough for me if it' d be possible to set the starting position with a server side value.

Just to make sure: i need the countdown (countup) to happen to the positive direction (after 2m17 comes 2m18), and it should be able to display hours, minutes and seconds.

Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with "set the starting position with a server side value"? Looks like you need help passing a value from server to client?

Comment: If you are using django-template, you could render the start position to the template and works with the jquery plugin you provided.

Comment: I don' t have problem rendering the value, but i' ve problem setting it. For instance i can set the time from the server using by: date = new Date({{ values from server}});  $('.demo3').countid({dateTime: date}), but this will still use the client side Time. I' d like to start the counter from 2m34s whatever the time is (of course 2m34s comes from the server in any format).